# Angular filter select lists excluding selected value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dynamic html block for which a user can add multiple select lists. I'm wanting to disable the selections that the user has made in the previous lists by checking using a custom filter. The part i'm struggling with how to pass the dynamic model into the filter and check that the value does not exist on the already generated select lists.

I've created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AQIXvMMbjd6oqBT7TI1a?p=preview). I appreciate the help.

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-init="things=[{id:0,name:'thing1'},{id:1,name:'thing2'},{id:2,name:'thing3'},{id:3,name:'thing4'}]">
<select ng-model="fields.option1" ng-options="thing.name for thing in things | excludeFrom:fields.option2"></select>
<select ng-model="fields.option2" ng-options="thing.name for thing in things | excludeFrom:fields.option1"></select>
<select ng-model="fields.option2" ng-options="thing.name for thing in things | excludeFrom:fields.option1,fields.option2"></select>
```

```
angular.module('app',[])
.filter('excludeFrom', [function () {
return function (things, selectedValue) {
    if (!angular.isUndefined(things) && !angular.isUndefined(selectedValue)) { //&& selectedValue.length > 0) {
        var tempThings = [];
        angular.forEach(selectedValue, function (name) {
            angular.forEach(things, function (things) {
                if (angular.equals(things, selectedValue.name)) {
                     tempThings.push(things);
                }
            });
        });
        return tempThings;
    } else {
        return things;
    }
};
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a predefined Angular feature that does what you want to do. A filter in Angular can be negated, which means that you can specifically exclude options from your selection. I recommend using ng-init on your selects though, otherwise you might run into undefined filter options.

Here is some code displaying my solution:

```
<select ng-model="select1" ng-init="select1 = things[0]" ng-options="thing.name for thing in things | filter:{name:'!'+select2.name}"></select>
<select ng-model="select2" ng-init="select2 = things[1]" ng-options="thing.name for thing in things | filter:{name:'!'+select1.name}"></select>
```

And [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YpXqY67hQoIplEmFcfqa?p=preview) is a plnkr showing it in action.

For further reading on filters you might want to check out the API [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

---

You can also handle the select part as an Array like so

```
<select ng-model="select[0]" ng-init="select[0] = things[0]" 
    ng-options="thing.name for thing in things | filter:{name:'!'+select[1].name}"></select>
    <select ng-model="select[1]" ng-init="select[1] = things[1]" 
    ng-options="thing.name for thing in things | filter:{name:'!'+select[0].name}"></select>
```

---

However if you want to have a dynamic selection, you will have to write a custom filter which i did like so:

**Filter:**

```
.filter('exclude', [function () {
  return function(input,select,selection){
    var newInput = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
      var addToArray=true;
      for(var j=0;j<select.length;j++){
          if(select[j].name===input[i].name){
              addToArray=false;
          }
      }
      if(addToArray || input[i].name === selection.name){
        newInput.push(input[i]);
      }
    }
    return newInput;
  };
```

**And usage:**

```
<div ng-repeat="sel in select">
      <select ng-model="select[$index]" ng-init="sel" 
    ng-options="thing.name for thing in things | exclude:select:sel"></select>
</div>
```

And [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1n8GzP5zPe62ZEm6x4x4?p=preview) is a plunkr showing this solution.

Comment: Hi @Bricktop, I was trying to pass the model in dynamically. Is this not possible?

Comment: Hi @Jimi , I am not sure what you mean with a dynamic model; I guess a model that has a dynamic length? This should be possible but is probably harder to achieve. I will try to find a solution but it might take some time.

Comment: if I pass in the value in from ng-model="select1" to the filter explicitly it works. If I try to pass the whole model, with multiple values in I get parse errors. Surely, this can be passed as an object ?

Comment: I edited my answer, you need two objects if I understand you correctly. One to save the current selection in an array and one to save all possible options and eclude the selected ones.

Comment: if I pass in the value in from ng-model="select1" to the filter explicitly it works. If I try to pass the whole model, with multiple values in, I get parse errors. Surely, this can be passed as an object ?  ng-model="selectModels" , filter:selectModels"

Comment: Okay I think I finally got what you mean, I will edit my answer in a minute.